# Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with publish my updated app, first time it publish successfully , but now its showing validate error:

> Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.

Can anyone suggest any ideas how we might handle this problem going forward?

Comment: The issue is not related with `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` code, check whether you are taking UDID in your app, also if you are using any third party library, ensure those are not utilizing the uniqueIdentifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDID has no relation with `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` ,check in your code if you are using unique identifier or any third party libraries like admob, bugsense etc because they are accessing UDID in there older frameworks